# Custom border around QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, border, qgraphicsview

I have this image :
[image]

I want the border of my `GraphicsView`become exactly like this image.

(consider the bellow image I want the top white rectangle become that shape)[image]

I inherit a class from `QGraphicsView` and tried drawing this image in both `drawBackground` and `paintEvent` but none of them works.

My code :

**.h file**

```
class GraphicsTraxSuggestionView : public QGraphicsView {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    GraphicsTraxSuggestionView(QWidget* widget);

protected:
//  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
    void drawBackground(QPainter *p, const QRectF &rect);
private:

};
```

**.cpp file**

```
GraphicsTraxSuggestionView::GraphicsTraxSuggestionView(QWidget* widget)
    : QGraphicsView(widget)
{
    //setFrameShadow(QFrame::Raised);
    setFrameStyle(QFrame::NoFrame);
    setStyleSheet("QGraphicsView { border-style: none; }");
}
void GraphicsTraxSuggestionView::drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect)
{
    painter->drawImage(rect, QImage("suggestionBorder.png"));
}
```

result of my code : https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0waP.png

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Could you add you non-working `drawBackground` implementation to the question ?

Comment: How do you set the size of your GW ? Could you log `rect` and `QImage("suggestionBorder.png").rect()` ?

Comment: @Ilya I want the view to take shape of the image . I'm not sure why you think size is important ?

Comment: It's the other way around, the image can stretch to fit the view but you have to set a view size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried `setMask()` and now it works fine .

```
GraphicsTraxSuggestionView::GraphicsTraxSuggestionView(QWidget* widget,QGraphicsScene* scene)
    : QGraphicsView(widget),
    scene_(scene)
{
    setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;");

    QPixmap myPixmap = QPixmap(":/Game/Tiles//suggestionBorder.png").scaled
        (scene_->sceneRect().size().width(),scene_->sceneRect().size().height());
    setMask(myPixmap.mask());
    setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
}

void GraphicsTraxSuggestionView::drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect)
{   
    painter->drawImage(scene_->sceneRect(), QImage(":/Game/Tiles//suggestionBorder.png"));
}
```

result :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a `QGraphicsScene` having the size of you image

2) Set it as the view's scene

3) Draw in the `drawBackground` as you're doing now

Comment: It draw border around view , but it's not what I want . I don't want the white area outside the image . I want the shape of widget exactly match the border..http://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn539.png

Comment: So you want to crop the image by removing the white parts outside of the line ?

Comment: Use `QImage::copy()` then to crop it.